# Can we add Html id to React code and make a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have an array,here I want to render the values based on span id's

```
let wheelIndex = 1
finalarray.forEach((wheel) => {
        axles.push(
          <div className='twoaxlewheels'>
          <span className='infotype' id={wheelIndex}>
            {wheel.wheel==id && wheel.sub_item?wheel.pressure:'defaultvalue'}
          </span>
          <span className='infotype' id={wheelIndex+1}>-</span>
        </div>
        )
    })
```

When I run this code it's throwing id is undefined.Is there a way to link span id to condition

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use an index in Array.forEach in javascript, but I'm not sure what your wheel.wheel == id is for. Also, you'll want to add a key for react to the outer div.

```
finalarray.forEach((wheel, wheelIndex) => {
        axles.push(
          <div key={wheelIndex} className='twoaxlewheels'>
          <span className='infotype' id={wheelIndex}>
            {wheel.wheel==wheelIndex && wheel.sub_item?wheel.pressure:'defaultvalue'}
          </span>
          <span className='infotype' id={wheelIndex}>-</span>
        </div>
        )
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. When you are using forEach you dont have keep track of index yourself, forEach gives you the flexibility.

```
let wheelIndex = 1
finalarray.forEach((wheel, index) => { // index here
        // you can also define an id here like this
        const id = wheelIndex;
        axles.push(
          <div className='twoaxlewheels'>
          <span className='infotype' id={id}> // use defined id here 
            {wheel.wheel===index && wheel.sub_item?wheel.pressure:'defaultvalue'}
          </span>
          <span className='infotype' id={wheelIndex+1}>-</span>
        </div>
        )
    })
```

Also you should use === for the equality comparison to check both value and type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing data to a new array I suggest you use `.map()` instead.

```
const axles = finalarray.map((wheel, index) => {
        return (
          <div className='twoaxlewheels'>
          <span className="infotype" id={index}> // use defined id here 
            {wheel.wheel===index && wheel.sub_item ? wheel.pressure :'defaultvalue'}
          </span>
          <span className="infotype" id={index}>-</span>
        </div>
        )
    });
```

You can do stuff (and render) the `axles` variable (which is an array)

Answer (score 0):

You can't supply `id` which starts with a number. so you need to add `string` at the beginning of id.

```
finalarray.forEach((wheel,wheelIndex) => {
    axles.push(
      <div className='twoaxlewheels'>
      <span className='infotype' id={`wheel_${wheelIndex}`}>
        {wheel.wheel==id && wheel.sub_item?wheel.pressure:'defaultvalue'}
      </span>
      <span className='infotype' id={`wheel_${wheelIndex}`}>-</span>
    </div>
    )
})
```

and I suggest you use `.map()`.